# What happens with the element-value of top_node after pop-function, C++

Tags: c++

I create this pop()-function:

```
void stack::pop(){
assert(!empty());
element* p=top_node;
top_node = top_node -> next;
delete p;
}
```

The top_node and the p pointer are pointing to the uppermost Element in the stack. After the top_node-Pointer points to the next element, p will be deleted. But p is just a Pointer, what happens with the whole element(int i, element* e). Do i have to clear it separately? or more precisely, to every pop and push function belongs actually a clean function?

Thank you!

Comment: That "clean function" you refer to is called *destructor*.

Comment: `delete` destroys the object by calling its destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens if a pointer p points to a user-defined type

```
class X{
    X() {};
    ~X(){};
};

X* p = new X; // calls default constructor
delete p; // calls destructor
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical overload used when the operator delete is called is `void delete(void *ptr);`

Provided the `ptr` argument points to a C++ object, the object's destructor is called. After the destructor has been called, the memory is de-allocated.